# C# Select Programs's Form

Tags: c#, forms, active-form

I want to select the form of my application to edit settings of a textbox in it. I used `Form.ActiveForm` for this. This works great while the Form is in foreground, but when it's not selected, this doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to get the applications current form, even when it is in background?

EDIT: Here's some code:

```
var form = Form.ActiveForm as MainForm;
if (form != null)
{
    form.txtChatOutput.Text += p.Data[0] + "\r\n";
}
```

EDIT 2:

I found a easy solution. Declare a Variable Form myForm; in the class and in your form's Shown event, set it to Form.ActiveForm.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form myForm;
    ....
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myForm = Form.ActiveForm;
    }
}
```

You can then access your form using myForm, even if it's not selected anymore.

Comment: It'd be useful if you posted some code

Comment: Iterate `Application.OpenForms` looking for the specific form you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the method provided in `Edit 2` will work, there are more direct ways.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 mainFrm;

    public Form2(Form1 frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainFrm = frm;
    }
    ...
}
```

Change the constructor for a "child" form to take an arg indicating the owner/parent or main form and store it as a class var. Do this for a form which *always* must be told know the parent/main form. To use the form both ways, just *add* the above as an overloaded ctor.  Using it:

```
using (Form2 frm = new Form2(this) )
{
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

If/when your app is class driven rather than form driven, you can do something similar from `Main` passing the main form reference to that class in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot completely understand what it is you wish to achieve, you could take a look at

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform(v=vs.110).aspx

For instance, if you have a textbox in your form, you could do sth like:

```
//// Get the form that the TextBox control is contained within.
Form myForm = textBoxInstance.FindForm();
```

Or, as pointed out in a comment, iterate through all OpenForms and retrieve the one you want:

```
// Loop through all the forms
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
   // identify the form you want somehow...
   // example using form name
   if (form.Name == "myForm")
      Form myForm = form;
}
```